# Redirect a livestream captured by FFmpeg to Azure Blob Storage in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

## The Goal

I want to make a POC that allows me to upload a part of a RTMP stream to azure blob storage, using `ffmpeg`. In my case this will be done with Azure functions as a QueueTrigger background job.
Currently I manually close ffmpeg (pressing `q` in terminal) so the stream ends and can be fully written to the blob storage.

I use Emulated Storage with Azurite and locally hosted Azure functions

### Progress

I found enough info about how to make ffmpeg work with `C#`

```
var process = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.FileName = "ffmpeg";
process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Arguments = "-i rtmp://10.10.10.4/live/test -loglevel panic -f flv pipe:1";
```

This should start ffmpeg with no logs `-loglevel panic`, correct format `-f flv`and pipe it to standard output `pipe:1`.

Then I access the blob container and create a new file:

```
uniqueFileName = string.Format(@"{0}" + ".flv", Guid.NewGuid());
blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(uniqueFileName);
```

### Current problem

**Uploading to the blob storage**. It seems there is no method that works.

#### Attempt 1: Upload Async

I would start the process and tell the blobclient to upload whatever is on the stream.

```
var runningProcess = Process.Start(process);
await blob.UploadAsync(runningProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream, true);
```

This results in the following error when accessing the `StorageExplorer`:
`The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined`
This also breaks the blob container, it must be deleted and another container must be made.

#### Attempt 2: OpenWriteAsync

I would open the Blob's stream and write to it as the ffmpeg stream went on.

```
using (var stream = await blob.OpenWriteAsync(true))
{
    log.LogInformation("Starting FFmpeg");
    var runningProcess = Process.Start(process);
    log.LogInformation("Started FFMPEG");


    while ((bytesRead = runningProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer)) != 0)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    
}
```

The same error occurred, though I seem closer to actually writing content to the blob as the live stream progresses.

At this point I wonder if it is possible to do what I intend.
I looked at multiple other threads that worked with files, but all are using completed files, not stream that are still being written to.

Comment: I also found this issue when I looked up my error: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/6008
I don't know if this is my exact issue however since I don't know if I even correctly uploaded my stream

Comment: Looks like the same issue to me; it's a bug in Storage Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right. I was able to get the blob and download it to a file locally and it's all fine. I don't have access to a live Storage Account, but when I do I will double check and maybe close the issue.

Comment: @StephenCleary For some reason I did not update this thread, it's a indeed a problem with Storage Explorer. 
If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I can the mark the question as Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is correct - as the comments suggest it is a bug that will be solved in 1.26.0. [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/6008)